# Add a dependency to a systemd automount

Tags: mount, systemd, automounting

I have a esata drive that is connected to a normal sata port. The device is not discovered automatically, but can be scanned for manually by issuing

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/scan
```

I have a systemd mount and automount unit to mount the device automatically when discovered, but I would like to discover the device automatically as well. My unit files look like this:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/media-data.mount
[Unit]
Description = data disk

[Mount]
What = LABEL=data
Where = /media/data
Type = ntfs

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

and

```
# /etc/systemd/system/media-data.automount
[Unit]
Description = data disk

[Automount]
Where = /media/data

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Can a .mount or .automount unit contain an execPre or dependency on another (oneshot?) unit?

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler to use `systemctl enable media-data.mount` to have it enabled upon reboot.

Comment: yes, but that would not work in case the esata disk is not connected on boot, and would not scan for the device itself

Comment: YEs, some of the pains with systemd taking control of the /etc/fstab ;(

Comment: Good points. Perhaps my answer should be a comment instead.